# Karate Chop Kata

Tags: algorithm, unit-testing, vba, binary-search, rubberduck

I had some time to kill today, and I found the [Karate Chop Kata](http://codekata.com/kata/kata02-karate-chop/).

> **Specification**:
>
> Write a binary chop method that takes an integer search target and a sorted array of integers. It should return the
>   integer index of the target in the array, or -1 if the target is not
>   in the array.

I've never implemented a binary search before. So, even though all of my tests pass, I'm not sure that I've covered all of the corner cases. It also doesn't look very elegant. How can I improve on this?

I'm also *still* not sure that I'm unit testing in a "proper" way. How can I improve them? (Please keep in mind that [Rubberduck automatically inserts boilerplate for new test methods.](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/wiki/Unit-Testing#quickstart))

### Chop

```
Option Explicit

' Returns index of the target number in a given array.
'   If not found returns -1
Public Function Chop(target As Long, Arr() As Long, Optional midpoint As Long = -1) As Long
    Dim result As Long
    Dim currentTest As Long

    If Not IsArrayAllocated(Arr) Then
        Chop = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    If midpoint < 0 Then
        midpoint = UBound(Arr) \ 2  'integer division
    End If

    currentTest = Arr(midpoint)

    If target = currentTest Then
        result = midpoint
    ElseIf midpoint = 0 Or (Arr(UBound(Arr)) < target) Then
        result = -1 'not found
    Else
        If target > currentTest Then
            midpoint = midpoint + (midpoint \ 2) ' go up by half
            If midpoint > UBound(Arr) Then midpoint = UBound(Arr)
        Else
            midpoint = midpoint \ 2
        End If

        result = Chop(target, Arr, midpoint)
    End If

    Chop = result
End Function

'Borrorwed from Chip Pearson
' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx
Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And _
                       Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And _
                       LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)
End Function
```

### Rubberduck Unit Tests

```
Option Explicit

Option Private Module

'@TestModule
Private Assert As New Rubberduck.AssertClass

'@TestMethod
Public Sub EmptyArrayReturnsNegativeOne()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = -1
    Dim integers() As Long
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(2, integers)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TargetNotInArrayReturnsNegativeOne()
    On Error GoTo TestFail
Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = -1
    Const target As Long = 2
    Dim integers(0) As Long
    integers(0) = 3
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(target, integers)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TargetNotInArrayReturnsNegativeOne_LargerArray()
    On Error GoTo TestFail
Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = -1
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(10, EvenSizeArray)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub OddSizeArray_FirstReturnsZero()
    On Error GoTo TestFail
Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = 0
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(1, OddSizeArray)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub OddSizeArray_MiddleReturnsTwo()
    On Error GoTo TestFail
Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = 2
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(3, OddSizeArray)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub OddSizeArray_LastReturnsFour()
    On Error GoTo TestFail
Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = 4
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(5, OddSizeArray)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub EvenSizeArray_FirstReturnsZero()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = 0
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(1, EvenSizeArray)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub EvenSizeArray_LastReturnsFive()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = 5
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(6, EvenSizeArray)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub EvenSizeArray_NextToLastReturnsFour()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = 4
Act:

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(5, EvenSizeArray)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

Private Function OddSizeArray() As Long()
    Dim result(0 To 4) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        result(i) = i + 1
    Next
    OddSizeArray = result
End Function

Private Function EvenSizeArray() As Long()
    Dim result(0 To 5) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        result(i) = i + 1
    Next
    EvenSizeArray = result
End Function
```

[image: Passing Tests]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Even though it matches the spec, `Chop` isn't a very good name for
   what this function does. `IndexOf` would be a better name.
2. `Ubound(Arr)` gets called in this code ***a lot***. It happens more
   than enough to declare a variable for it.
3. All of the parameters are being implicitly passed `ByRef` which isn't nice. (And you have no excuse. The add-in you're using warns you about this.)
4. The optional parameter for `midpoint` is *okay*, but it exposes implementation details to the client. It would be better to create a private function that does all of the heavy lifting. It can require that the midpoint be specified.

   ```
   Public Function IndexOf(ByVal target As Long, ByRef Arr() As Long) As Long
       IndexOf = RecursiveIndexOf(target, Arr, -1)
   End Function
   ```
5. This is a useless comment. If the maintainer doesn't know the difference between `/` and `\` they can look it up.

   > ```
   > midpoint = upperBoundry \ 2  'integer division
   > ```
6. `-1` is a magic number with two separate meanings. Constants should be defined.

   ```
   Private Const DefaultMidpoint As Integer = -1
   Public Const IndexOfResultNotFound As Long = -1
   ```
7. It's not semantically correct to initialize the midpoint if `midpoint < 0`. It's correct to initialize it if `midpoint = DefaultMidpoint`.

   ```
   If midpoint = DefaultMidpoint Then
       midpoint = upperBoundry \ 2
   End If
   ```
8. It's not quite as DRY, but an `ElseIf` here instead of an `Or` improves readability. Considering it's merely assignment, I think it's a good change.

   ```
   ElseIf midpoint = 0 Or (Arr(upperBoundry) < target) Then
       result = IndexOfResultNotFound
   Else
   ```

   Becomes

   ```
   ElseIf midpoint = 0 Then
       result = IndexOfResultNotFound

   ElseIf Arr(upperBoundry) < target Then
       result = IndexOfResultNotFound

   Else
   ```
9. This logic can and should be extracted into a `GetNextMidpoint` function.

   > ```
   >     Else
   >         If target > currentTest Then
   >             midpoint = midpoint + (midpoint \ 2) ' go up by half
   >             If midpoint > upperBoundry Then
   >                 midpoint = upperBoundry
   >             End If
   >         Else
   >             midpoint = midpoint \ 2
   >         End If
   >
   >         result = RecursiveIndexOf(target, Arr, midpoint)
   >     End If
   > ```

Which gives us the refactored code below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const DefaultMidpoint As Integer = -1
Public Const IndexOfResultNotFound As Long = -1

' Returns index of the target number in a given array.
'   If not found returns -1
Public Function IndexOf(ByVal target As Long, ByRef Arr() As Long) As Long
    IndexOf = RecursiveIndexOf(target, Arr, DefaultMidpoint)
End Function

Private Function RecursiveIndexOf(ByVal target As Long, ByRef Arr() As Long, ByVal midpoint As Long)
    Dim result As Long
    Dim currentTest As Long

    If Not IsArrayAllocated(Arr) Then
        RecursiveIndexOf = IndexOfResultNotFound
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim upperBoundry As Long
    upperBoundry = UBound(Arr)

    If midpoint = DefaultMidpoint Then
        midpoint = upperBoundry \ 2
    End If

    currentTest = Arr(midpoint)

    If target = currentTest Then
        result = midpoint

    ElseIf midpoint = 0 Then
        result = IndexOfResultNotFound

    ElseIf Arr(upperBoundry) < target Then
        result = IndexOfResultNotFound

    Else
        midpoint = GetNextMidpoint(currentTest, target, upperBoundry, midpoint)
        result = RecursiveIndexOf(target, Arr, midpoint)
    End If

    RecursiveIndexOf = result
End Function

Private Function GetNextMidpoint(ByVal current As Long, ByVal target As Long, ByVal upperBoundry As Long, ByVal midpoint As Long) As Long
    Dim result As Long

    If target > current Then
        result = midpoint + (midpoint \ 2) ' go up by half
        If result > upperBoundry Then
            result = upperBoundry
        End If
    Else
        result = midpoint \ 2
    End If

    GetNextMidpoint = result

End Function

'Borrorwed from Chip Pearson
' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx
Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And _
                       Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And _
                       LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

I see some weird stuff going on here, let me see if I can verbalize my concerns

> ```
> If target = currentTest Then
>     result = midpoint
> ElseIf midpoint = 0 Or (Arr(UBound(Arr)) < target) Then
>     result = -1 'not found
> Else
>     If target > currentTest Then
>         midpoint = midpoint + (midpoint \ 2) ' go up by half
>         If midpoint > UBound(Arr) Then midpoint = UBound(Arr)
>     Else
>         midpoint = midpoint \ 2
>     End If
>
>     result = Chop(target, Arr, midpoint)
> End If
> ```

One of the first things I would do is to move the `ElseIf` statement out front, dump out right away, but I have a feeling that this won't happen as often as the current `If` statement and that the `Arr(UBound(Arr)) < target` must be more Resource intensive than comparing two objects.

so I guess that I am going to leave that one alone.

The next thing that I noticed was that you nested an `If` structure inside the `Else` statement, and it made me stop and think for a little bit.

So I wrote it out like this

```
If target = currentTest Then
    result = midpoint
ElseIf midpoint = 0 Or (Arr(UBound(Arr)) < target) Then
    result = -1 'not found
Else If target > currentTest Then
    midpoint = midpoint + (midpoint \ 2) ' go up by half
    If midpoint > UBound(Arr) Then midpoint = UBound(Arr)
    result = Chop(target, Arr, midpoint)
Else
    midpoint = midpoint \ 2
    result = Chop(target, Arr, midpoint)
End If
```

But then the code isn't dry, it repeats `result = Chop(target, Arr, midpoint)` which is annoying, and now I understand why you did it like that, it smells but seems to be what is necessary.

---

But your `If` statement structure is inconsistent, you one line in a weird spot and I almost missed it.  You were also missing an `End If` statement.  I came up with

```
If target = currentTest Then
    result = midpoint
ElseIf midpoint = 0 Or (Arr(UBound(Arr)) < target) Then
    result = -1 'not found
Else
    If target > currentTest Then
        midpoint = midpoint + (midpoint \ 2) ' go up by half
        If midpoint > UBound(Arr) Then 
            midpoint = UBound(Arr)
        End If
    Else
        midpoint = midpoint \ 2
    End If
    result = Chop(target, Arr, midpoint)
End If
```

Comment: I don't think I can move the `ElseIf` out front because I think  I need to check to see if a match was found before I say it wasn't found, but otherwise spot on. (Particularly that one line `If`...What was I thinking?)

Comment: I figured that there had to be a reason that you had that second and not first.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just comment on your unit testing code.

Your unit tests aren't really AAA:

> ```
> Arrange:
>     Const expected As Long = -1
>     Dim integers() As Long
> Act:
>
> Assert:
>     Assert.AreEqual expected, Chop(2, integers)
> ```

You're doing the "Act" step in the "Assert" part, which should do nothing other than *assert* - like this:

```
Arrange:
    Const expected As Long = -1
    Dim integers() As Long
    Dim result As Long

Act:
    result = Chop(2, integers)

Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual expected, result
```

---

`OddSizeArray` and `EvenSizeArray` are *setup code* that shouldn't be called in the "Act" part (even less so in the "Assert" part).

Rubberduck unit tests allow you to move the call to that setup code outside the actual test method, so that creating the setup array doesn't affect the measurements (although 0-1ms is arguably not a big deal).

Consider adding private fields:

```
Private oddSizedArray() As Long
Private evenSizedArray() As Long
```

And then add a `TestInitialize` method that will populate them:

```
'@TestInitialize
Public Sub SetupTestArrays()
    oddSizedArray = OddSizeArray
    evenSizedArray = EvenSizeArray
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can drop the `'@TestInitialize` marker comment and name the method like this:

```
Public Sub TestInitialize()
```

Every method called `TestInitialize` or marked with a `@TestInitialize` marker right above the signature line will execute *before* every unit test in a test module, i.e. *before Rubberduck makes the timed method call to run the test method*. As a result, setting up the two arrays will not count in the `Duration` of a test.

The fields should "die" by themselves when all tests have executed, but if you want you can also add a `TestCleanup` method that runs *after* every unit test, to deallocate the arrays:

```
 Public Sub TestCleanup()
     Erase oddSizedArray
     Erase evenSizedArray
 End Sub
```

---

In this specific case, we're talking about nanoseconds. But in other unit testing code you could be setting up a mock of an interface implementation to supply fake content to a method that would otherwise access a database or the file system: that setup code belongs in the "Arrange" part of your tests - not in "Act", not in "Assert".

Comment: For the record, Rubberduck didn't support this when I first wrote these tests. =;)-